# Save data to another model cakePHP 3.5

Tags: php, database, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm still beginner in cakephp. I have table question and questionQuizzes. I have created the form named existingQuestion in question controller and want to save it in table questionQuizzes. However, the form cannot be saved. I have followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707646/cakephp-3-saving-to-an-different-table) but it still cannot be saved.

This is QuestionController

```
public function existingQuestion()
{  

    //echo "here<br><br>";
    //$QuestionQuizzesTable = 
    $this->loadModel('QuestionQuizzes');
    $questions = $this->paginate($this->Questions);
    $questionQuiz = $this->QuestionQuizzes->newEntity();

    //print_r($this->request->getData());
    //die();

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {

        $questionQuiz = $this->QuestionQuizzes->patchEntity($questionQuiz, $this->request->getData());
        print_r($this->request->getData());
        die();

        if ($this->QuestionQuizzes->save($questionQuiz)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The question has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'existingQuestion']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The question could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    //$this->Questions->saveAll($this->request->getData());
    $this->set(compact('questions'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['questions']);
}
```

Can somebody help me??!

Edited 3:
This is my existing_questions.ctp

```
<?php

 /**
 * @var \App\View\AppView $this
 * @var \App\Model\Entity\Question[]|\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface 
  $questions
  */
  use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
  ?>
  <nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
   <ul class="side-nav">
    <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Courses'), ['controller' => 'Courses',  
    'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
   </nav>
    <div class="questions form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Question') ?></legend>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create($questionQuiz) ?>  
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('checked') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('question') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('marks') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($questions as $question): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Form->checkbox('questions[].', ['value' => 
            $question['id'], 'name' => 'question[id][]', 'checked'=>false, 
                'hiddenField' => false])?></td>
               <td><?= $this->Number->format($question->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($question->question) ?></td>
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($question->marks) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>                 
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">        
    </form>
    <div class="paginator">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?= $this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('first')) ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
        <?= $this->Paginator->last(__('last') . ' >>') ?>
    </ul>
    <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter(['format' => __('Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} record(s) out of {{count}} total')]) ?></p>
     <?php //$this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['action' => 'existingQuestion'])
         $this->Form->submit('Save'); 
        // $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Edited 4:
I have table quizzes which contains id and quiz id. And I have table questions contains id, question id, questions and marks. Then, I have table questionQuizzes which contains quiz id and question id.

Here is quizzesTable.php model:

```
class QuizzesTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('quizzes');
    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Courses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Attempts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'quiz_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Gradebooks', [
        'foreignKey' => 'quiz_id'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->scalar('title')
        ->requirePresence('title', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('title');

    return $validator;
}

/**
 * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
 * application integrity.
 *
 * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
 * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
 */
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['course_id'], 'Courses'));

    return $rules;
}
}
```

Here is questionsTable.php

```
class QuestionsTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('questions');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasMany('QuestionQuizzes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->scalar('question')
        ->requirePresence('question', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('question');

    $validator
        ->numeric('marks')
        ->requirePresence('marks', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('marks');

    return $validator;
}
}
```

EDITED:
existques function:

```
public function existQues()
{
    $questions = TableRegistry::get('questions');
    $query = $questions->find();

    foreach ($query as $row) 
    {
        $quizzes = $this->paginate($this->Quizzes);

        $this->set(compact('quizzes'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['quizzes']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `$questionQuiz->errors()` when the save fails?

Comment: No. How should I do that? I'm sorry this is my first time use CakePHP.

Comment: `debug($questionQuiz->errors());`

Comment: I have edited the post. It shows error like that after I tried debug. Can you help me? I have tried so many ways but it still failed :(

Comment: @janedoe what is the output of `print_r($this->request->getData());`? Instead of `print_r` use `debug`

Comment: @AmanRawat I have edited the posts and include the output of print_r and debug. I really hope you can help me :(. Thank youu

Comment: It "shows error at the debug line to itself" because that's part of what debug does: it outputs the data in a human-friendly format, plus includes details about where that happened, in case you have multiple similar debug statements and need to know which one it was.

Comment: Please provide model as well and if you want to save multiple records in the table https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities. Also provide the table structure of the table

Comment: @AmanRawat I have edited the post. Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the wrong format. Where did you find this? It should look like this:

```
[
    'questions' => [
        '_ids' => [
            0 => 60,
            1 => 61,
        ]
    ]
]
```

Note that questions is now lower case and plural, and id is replaced with _ids. See [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data) for more details.

You will also want to move this to the Quizzes controller (as I suggested [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581458/merge-index-and-add-action-into-form-in-cakephp-3-5)) and do `patchEntity` on a quiz entity (through the Quizzes model), because right now the data you have is meaningless: how does it know what quiz it's supposed to be adding these questions to?

Comment: I have read about saving data. But, I'm still not sure how to do it. The quiz id  I thought I will get it from the url using $this->request->pass but is it a right way to get the quiz id? Can you help to look at my code? I have edited the post. I really hope you can help with my final year project :(

Comment: I'm not going to hand you code that solves your homework for you. You haven't referenced `$this->request->pass` anywhere. The code doesn't magically know where to get such data. You need to get the quiz id, load that quiz, patch that entity with data formatted like I've shown, and save the resulting entity. As I've said twice before now, this will all be easier for you if the function is in the Quizzes controller.

Comment: I tried to put the function into Quizzes controller as you suggested. But first I need to display all of the data from questions table into a form with multiple checkbox in the Quizzes controller named existques.ctp. I have made query as you suggested before to get data from questions table. However, the error said 'Undefined variable: question'. I have edited the post and include the exisques function. I hope you can take a look and give some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: I barely even know where to start here. You don't tell us where the "undefined variable" error happens, and as far as I can tell the code where that is occurring isn't included here anywhere. You've got a bunch of code pasted in, but much of it is now irrelevant. Your existques function is basically meaningless, you're getting a paginated list of quizzes in the system, once for each question but without referencing the questions anywhere at all? You said this is a school project. It seems like you've got some serious issues with understanding the basics and should talk to your teacher or a TA.