# CakePHP 3.5 saving into another table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm very new in cakephp 3.5 and I got problem with saving the data into different table. I have Question table and want to save the data into QuestionQuizzes table by using the checkbox function. When i try to submit the form, it got error saying 'The question could not be save".

QuestionController:

```
public function existingQuestion()
{  

    $this->loadModel('QuestionsQuizzes');
    $questions = $this->paginate($this->Questions);
    $questionsQuiz = $this->QuestionsQuizzes->newEntity();

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {

        $question = $this->QuestionsQuizzes->patchEntity($questionsQuiz, 
        $this->request->getData());

        if ($this->Questions->save($questionsQuiz)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The question has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'existingQuestion']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The question could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

    }

    $this->set(compact('questions'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['questions']);
}
```

I just need the checked data can be saved into the database table.

**Edited**:
So i put the hidden filed for quiz id in my ctp page, because it seems in the array it missing the quiz id. but when i put the hidden field and try to debug it i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5U6S.jpg) error.

existing_question.ctp

```
      <form method="post" action="">
        <?php echo $this->Form->create($question) ?>
        <?php foreach ($questions as $question): ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?= $this->Form->checkbox('id[].', array('value' => $question['id'], 'name' => 'Question[id][]', 'checked'=>false, 'hiddenField'=>false))?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?= h($question->question) ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?= $this->Number->format($question->marks) ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?= $this->Form->hidden('quiz_id', ['value' => $this->request->pass[2]]);?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['action' => 'existingQuestion', $this->request->pass[2]]) ?>
    </form>
    <div class="paginator">
      <ul class="pagination">

        <?= $this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('first')) ?>
          <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
              <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
                <?= $this->Paginator->last(__('last') . ' >>') ?>
      </ul>
      <p>
        <?= $this->Paginator->counter(['format' => __('Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} record(s) out of {{count}} total')]) ?>
      </p>
      <?php this->Form->submit('Save'); ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Then i was thinking maybe i should do the code in QuizController. I did it but got error with the paginator.

Comment: Why are you using `patchEntity` on a new entity?

Comment: @cgTag is it wrong?? i just copy the code from the add function and changed the variables name.

Comment: See what you get in `$question->getErrors();` rigth before `$this->Flash->error`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988273/save-data-to-another-model-cakephp-3-5/48012476. Flag function won't let me indicate that...

Comment: @Yaroslav i got nothing